# How to customise the textMateRules in order to colour the code inside a #pragma warning disable and a #pragma warning restore statement in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor, settings, pragma, dynamics-al

I find hard to tell what code will be run by just reading the code because the lines between a  #pragma warning disable and #pragma warning restore statements don't change colours

So i'd like to know if it's possible to do that with the textMateRules in settings.json

I've tried to change the colours but wasn't able to condition the colour changing correctly